# Dates and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, localization, datetime-format

I have a really strange bug, check out this Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/KEJsL/

It formats a date with `toString()` and `toLocaleString()`

I have admin rights since I'm a dev and have installed Chrome myself, my users however have gotten it through the package management order system at the company.

For me `toLocaleString` returns the correct formated date in the current selected culture, but for my users it return the same string as the `toString` does, something along the lines of

> Wed Oct 23 2013 16:40:47 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)

Why is this happening, whats have they done in the Chrome settings that can do this?

Comment: This doesn't sound like it would be Chrome specific... What results are you getting in other browsers?

Comment: It works for IE and FF. All machines with Chrome that are shipped through the order system gets the problem.

Comment: I meant that IE and FF works on the same machine were Chrome did not

Comment: Any chance you can get the `Accept-Language` header from the requests your user's are sending? If you can, compare it to what you're Chrome instance is sending to isolate where in issue might be. Header value should look something like `en-GB,en;q=0.8`

Comment: I did, im pretty sure they were the same, but will have to check again tomorrow when I'm back at work. also, the above string should never be returned for toLocaleString in any culture, its only valid for toString

Comment: Next company package release of Chrome will be 30.0.1599.101 and in that version it works, so maybe its a bug in the current version  22.0.1229.94. But I cant find anything on google, oh well, it will work once they release the new version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether arguments are passed or not.

`toLocaleString` without arguments depends on three things:

- the browser implementation
- the default locale
- the default time zone

`toLocaleString` was extended to support arguments as part of the [ECMA-402](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/) Internationalization API. Browser support for ECMA-402 is as follows:

```
Chrome Firefox  IE Opera Safari
24     29.0     11 15    N/A
```

**References**

- [MDN: toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)
- [ECMA-402 Conformance Test Suite](http://test262.ecmascript.org/testcases_intl402.html)